# Make fishnet visible but not snappable

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, shapefile, polygon, vector-grid

I'm currently using a polyline fishnet grid to use as a guide when labelling land features. For example, I aim to label 10 grids per day.

An issue I have is that when creating my polygons they keep snapping to the fishnet by accident.

How can I have the fishnet visible so that I can use it as a visual guide but not interactive, so I do not snap to it by accident when creating polygons?

I use both ArcGIS Pro and QGIS to create shapefiles, so need a solution that works across both software.

Note: it's important that I can still view the grid ID to keep a log, so I must be able to open the attribute table or view the grid number another way. E.g., a raster with grid numbers in the centre.

Comment: There cannot be one implementation that works for both QGIS and ArcGIS Pro. Please [Edit] this question to focus on one of the two.

Comment: Why not? If, for example, it is possible to convert the polyline fishnet to a raster with labels for each grid, would that not work as a solution across platforms?

Comment: But the *implementation* is different.  Choose one platform under which you'd make the change, try it, and see what happens.  If you have a problem, *then* you have a question topic.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to change the snapping status for the fishnet layer.

Both ArcGIS and QGIS support the enabling/disabling of snapping for individual layers.

For ArcGIS, if you select "list by snapping" under the contents pane you can tick snapping on/off for each layer.

For QGIS, select Edit Advanced Configuration tool under the snapping toolbar to configure which layers you are able to snap to.